# Sort result of query based on array

Tags: php, laravel, sorting

I have a table site which has columns like id, title, link,... 
Page is another table uses site's id as a foreign key. 
Page1 is a result of query for page table
    $page1 = Page::where('layer',2)->get();
I have sorted the result of $pape1 like this:

```
$page1 = $page1->sortByDesc('first')->toArray();
```

Now, i want to sort sites based on array $page1
using Site::whereIn('id',$page1) doesn't show the sorted result based on array

Comment: hi there. can you put where you initialize your `$page1`

Comment: $page1 = Site_layer1_show::where('layer1_id',$id)->get();

Comment: $table->integer('site_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('site_id')->references('id')->on('sites')->onDelete('cascade'); 
            $table->integer('layer1_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('layer1_id')->references('id')->on('layer1s')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->boolean('first')->default(0);

Comment: is that index `first` a column of your model `Site_layer1_show` ?

Comment: yes and it is boolean

Comment: seems your code fines to me

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please try to provide more information.